# Linebreak in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var y=21.5;
document.write(y);

var num = 10; 
document.write(num == 8);
```

Hi guys, it's my first time here to ask question in this forum. I am currently studying the basics of javascript and i want to know how can i put a linebreak after an integer. I've already tried putting 
 inside and outside variable y and i still can't get my desired result. Here's the output of my code.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWvtl.jpg

Comment: its rather a linebreak in html...

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `document.write`, what you need is a HTML line break, not a Javascript line break.

Try using `<br>`:

```js
var y = 21.5;
var num = 10; 

document.write(y + '<br>');
document.write(num == 8);
```

Comment: Hey Koby I have deleted my answer, after you have altered your answer from `\n´ to my solution... ;-)

Comment: Thanks koby! My code is now working. I just need to put "+" after an integer to insert linebreak.